# Code for making Java program run on startup

Tags: java, netbeans, startup, autorun

I'm writing a program in java and I was curious as to whether there was any command or code that could be added to make it always run on startup. For example once someone downloads the program it runs whenever they log into their computer. I'm not sure if this matters but I'm writing it in the Netbeans IDE.

Comment: That's going to be dependent on the operating system you use. For example, on Windows it's done by adding a shortcut to your program in the "Startup" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your application an option (user can choose it) that will create an entry in the startup/run-once part of the operating system. On windows you could write to the registry to set the option (maybe program need higher priv. to do that) or you could put a link to the startup folder. This might depend on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Try Java Service Wrapper
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html

This lets you run a Java application as a Windows Service or UNIX Daemon.